# How can i check servers' "JVM / CPU / Memory" at runtime?

Tags: java, api, plugins

When a job is created, I want to assign it to the less dense server. How can i check servers' "JVM / CPU / Memory" at runtime? (I have 4 server)(İt must return a value to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, with no external dependencies, by utilizing system properties and the Java Management API.

These properties are more then enough to determine the VM;

```
java.vm.specification.version   Java Virtual Machine specification version
java.vm.specification.vendor    Java Virtual Machine specification vendor
java.vm.specification.name  Java Virtual Machine specification name
java.vm.version         Java Virtual Machine implementation version
java.vm.vendor          Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor
java.vm.name            Java Virtual Machine implementation name
java.specification.version  Java Runtime Environment specification version
java.specification.vendor   Java Runtime Environment specification vendor
java.specification.name     Java Runtime Environment specification name
```

And you can use the following management beans to determine CPU and memory:

```
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you don't provide many informations. Do you want to check those informations programmatically? Which servers are used? What OS is installed on the server machine?

If you're using any kind of Sun Application Server (Glassfish/Oracle AppServ) you can use **jconsole**.
It's a [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) tool which lets you control your AppServer remotely.

It's shipped with your jdk and can be found in `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jconsole.exe`.

After startup youre able to connect to your remote machine via IP, port (in case of Glassfish 8686) and your user credentials.

A quick google-search showed up that its also able to monitor tomcat, jboss and websphere server by adding some configuration.

For example Tomcat:

- navigate to `%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/catalina.bat`
- insert row `SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` (after first commented block)
- restart server
- use jconsole

Hope this helped, have fun!